# When I run my code it says 'no module FirebaseFirestoreSwfit'

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I keep trying to improve the podfile but it still wont work. Here's the Podfile and code:

[image]

Comment: Instead of adding screenshots of your code, please add the actual code to the question. To capture the error message, right click on the red indicator and "Reveal in Issue Navigator".

Comment: Do a `pod install`, then go to XCode, do a `Shift + Command + K` (clean) and then `Command + B` (build). If it still gives you problems, then close and open back XCode, and then build again.

Answer (score 1):

Podfile has an issue due to which the project is unable to find the appropriate module.

Please see the screenshot how Podfile should look like.

[image: Podfile]

All the third-party libraries are supposed to be added below the tag `# Pods for [Project Name]`.

I tried and it worked for me. I hope it works for you too.

Comment: I also reloaded Xcode and it still doesn't work, I'm trying to send the image but it doesn't let me post

Comment: It still says 'no such module as FirebaseFirestoreSwift'

Comment: @Sinan after making the changes in Podfile did you run the `pod install` command again in the terminal.

Comment: @Sinan, I have uploaded the sample project on GitHub here is the [link of sample project](https://github.com/darshanPatel16/My-Quiz-pod-demo). Please download and see does it work for you. Make sure you run the `pod install` command before opening the app.

Comment: @Sinan is there any chance you can share the small piece of code on Github and share the link for further help.

Comment: Okay I've restarted the whole project because I think there was something in my previous code which didn't work. It'll take me 1-2 days to finish it. If I have the same problem I will post my code and podfile on GitHub. Thank you for the help till now

Comment: Sure @Sinan feel free to reach out any time. Happy to help you.